# Ajax GET call to webAPI

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api

In my javascript file i am trying to make a GET Request to my webAPI, the entire request is ignored. the two alerts before and after the request are outputted but nothing within my request.

This is my GET request made in my javascript file:

```
    alert("before Get");
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Map/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error in request");
    }

});
alert("after Get");
```

My WebAPI file and the method im trying to get:

```
    // GET: api/Map
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        SetContext();
        List<ICoordinate> BoundingBox = CreateBoundingBox(_LoadedConfiguration.StartPosition);
        List<string> LayerNames = _LoadedConfiguration.GetAllLayerNames();
        Map LoadedMap = new Map(BoundingBox, LayerNames, _persistenceFactory, _LoadedConfiguration);
        GeoJson.IGeoJsonGeometry MapFeatureCollections = (IGeoJsonGeometry)LoadedMap.GetAsGeoJsonObject();
        return new string[] { MapFeatureCollections.ToString()};
    }
```

I am trying to return the string of "MapFeatureCollections"

Comment: Look in the network tab of your browser. Check if the request ever leaves your browser, and the state of it.

Comment: it returns 404(not found) error

Comment: I haven't used ASP for a while, but I am pretty sure the endpoint is http://yourhost:port/Class/Action. I assume Class is ApiController or MapController and Action is Get. The request should be pointed to `/Map/Get/` or `Api/Get`.

Comment: Are you able to hit the endpoint from a browser window?  Postman?

Comment: i have resolved the issue of accessing my get method and webAPI it was due to an IIS error and the localHost that was being referenced.

Comment: @LajosZadravecz Can you please elaborate on how you fixed it. Since I'm too facing the same issue.